# Can a cast cause a buffer overrun?

Tags: c++

Is it possible for a buffer overflow to occur from a cast?

If so, please explain how.

thanks.

Comment: Sounds like homework. If it is, you should add the "homework" tag to your question.

Comment: Also, _just_ from a cast? Casts don't write to memory, so that would be pretty hard to cause a buffer overrun from them.

Comment: This could depend on the /type/ of cast used. Remember, C++ doesn't have only C-style casts.

Comment: Not homework. I'm running through a static analysis tool, and see "static_cast" causes buffer overrun.

Comment: What are you casting from and to?

Comment: If you see it then why not show us the code so we can see it and tell you what is going on rather than making wild speculative grasps at odd corner cases.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe:

```
char p[1];
int *b = static_cast<int *>(p);
*b = 1;
```

Voila, buffer overrun! But only the write would overrun, doing the cast itself is not an overrun.

Answer (score 3):

Only indirectly -- for example, if you have a buffer of char, and decide to work with Unicode so you cast the address of the buffer from `char *` to `wchar_t *`, but forget to adjust the number of "items" in that space to compensate for a `wchar_t` (normally) being larger than a `char`...

Answer (score 3):

Not really. A buffer overrun is caused by *writing* outside a buffer's boundary. So unless you do something stupid like this:

```
struct overrun
{
    explicit overrun(size_t pX)
    {
        char buffer[1];
        for (size_t i = 0; i < pX; ++i)
            buffer[i] = 5;
    }
};

int main()
{
    static_cast<overrun>(100); // oops
}
```

A cast isn't going to typically overrun a buffer. (And even here, one could argue it's not the cast that causes the overrun so much as its the construction). If you're having a real problem, ask.

Comment: @aaa: I don't think so. That's just undefined behavior (access violation).

Comment: "Buffer overrun" isn't a well-defined term. From a security perspective, a read overrun can cause an uninteneded information exposure. Also, a static analysis tool should not even bother trying to determine what you're going to do with an out-of-bounds pointer. The mere forming of such a pointer is already UB. (Except of course the +1 end pointer)

Answer (score 3):

Sort of, I suppose... say you have something like this:

```
class A
{
};

class B
{
public:
  operator A()
  {
    char buffer[5];
    strcpy(buffer, "1234512345"); // buffer overrun here

    A a;
    return a;
  }
};

// later...

B b;
A a = static_cast<A>(b); // triggers buffer overrun above
```

Technically, the cast is not required (since it's implicit) but that's one example where you could say it's possible. Of course, this is a silly example :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly how your analysis tool reports the culprit, but what about this?

```
char ra[] = "hi";
char &ref = ra[3];
std::cout << static_cast<int>(ref);
```

Of course it's evaluating the argument of the cast which has actually overrun, rather than the conversion as such.

GMan says that a read overrun doesn't count, but you could just as well assign the result of a cast to an out-of-bounds location, and some tool appear to report the cast as guilty.

Comment: Take what I say with a grain of salt, of course. I'm sure some people may consider an overrun *any* access to an out-of-bounds location.

Comment: @GMan: I guess the definition that matters, is the one used by Kevin's analysis tool. It would be more helpful if it did distinguish between the two cases.

Comment: @Gman: in common use, I'd argue a buffer overrun implies an out-of-bounds location reached by a bad index or excessive iteration from a buffer array, whereas a bad pointer dereference might have nothing to do with any such "buffer" (though there must have been intent to access a variable somewhere, and you could argue that any variable's a buffer). @Steve: could even distinguish as read buffer overrun and write buffer overrun.... ;-/